# Exception in Angular2 app

Tags: angular

I am getting this exception in console:

> Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:0:32 caused by: No provider for Http!

Why should I provide HTTP providers in app component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the following code in your App Module or whichever module declares `AppComponent`:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    // ...
    imports: [
        // ...
        HttpModule
    ]
    // ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For an example, see [this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#register-for-http-services) from Angular's tutorial.